# Update label within a task in ContentPage not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a class of ContentPage.

I create a task within the class and have this simple code:

```
async Task ScoutingTimeThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        i++;
        label.Text = i.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(1000 * 1);
    }
}
```

`i` is a member in the class

The label only updated once at the first time. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 5):

You need to be sure that UI updates are performed on the main thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
  label.Text = i.ToString();
});
```

Comment: @asaf : did you find the answer? I'm currently need.